# Netbeans autocomplete does not work inside a lambda expression

Tags: java, netbeans, lambda, anonymous-inner-class

I have encountered a strange bug in Netbeans 8.2.

When declaring an object with a lambda expression, autocomplete for variables inside the lambda does not seem to work, and instead I see global variables, suggestions for keywords amongst other things as shown in the screenshot.

[image]
As you can see, `testString` and `testString2` are nowhere in sight.

I have tried other objects and the result is always the same.

Now if we do the same with an anonymous inner class, we can see that our variables `testString` and `testString2` do appear.
[image]

Here is the sample code for you to try on your IDEs. I have also included an `ActionListener` to demonstrate that the problem doesn't lie with just one interface.

```
public class SOInner {

    private ActionListener listenerExampleLambda = e -> {
        //autocomplete DOES NOT work for these vars
        int testVarInner = 2;
        int testVarInner2 = 4;

    };

    private ActionListener listenerExampleClass = new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            //autocomplete works for these vars
            int testVarInner = 2;
            int testVarInner2 = 4;
        }
    };

    private Comparable<SOInner> comparableExampleLambda = o -> {
        //autocomplete DOES NOT work for these vars        
        String testString = "Hello";
        String testString2 = "Hi";        
        return 0;
    };

    private Comparable<SOInner> comparableExampleClass = new Comparable<SOInner>() {
        @Override
        public int compareTo(SOInner o) {
            //autocomplete works for these vars
            String testString = "Hello";
            String testString2 = "Hi";
            return 0;
        }
    };
}
```

Is there a solution for this bug or has it been recorded already?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: I have added the question now.

Comment: Did you file a bug report? https://issues.apache.org/jira/projects/NETBEANS

Comment: Will do now. Thanks for providing a link, the Bugzilla section on the Netbeans website is a mess.

Comment: I have reported this bug here:
https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/NETBEANS-326

Comment: Yes, I see the same problem in NetBeans8.2 with your declarations for listenerExampleLambda and comparableExampleLambda. And +1 for actually creating a bug report.

Comment: Something worth noting for your two failing examples is that if you break them up into declarations and assignments within an initializer block then they also work fine. For example, autocomplete works for this: _private Comparable<SOInner> comparableExampleLambda;  { comparableExampleLambda = o -> { yadda, yadda }};_